# Change WordPress logo with user uploaded logo

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created this plugin and I need it to get an image from user using an upload button and then replace the uploaded image with WordPress login page logo, Could you please help me? I have been searching for a long time for any codes related to this but I failed.

```
<?php 
/*
* Plugin Name: New Logo
* Plugin URI:
* Description: New logo
* Author: Zahra Sharafi
* Version: 1.0.0
* Author URI: http://www.averta.net/
* license: GPLv2+
* License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
* Text Domain: nw_logo
*/

  // Exit if accessed directly
      if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

   add_action('admin_menu','my_plugin_menu');

     function my_plugin_menu()
    {
       add_options_page('Add New Logo', 'Add New Logo', 'manage_options', 'my-   unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
    }
    function my_plugin_options()
    {
       echo '<div class="wrap">';
       echo '<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="button">';
       echo "Click Me";
       echo '</a>';
       echo '</div>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) [WP Custom Admin Login Page Logo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-login-page-logo/screenshots/)

2) [Customizing the Login Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)

3) [How to Change the Login Logo in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-login-logo-in-wordpress/)